# Maldet cron.daily script syntax error

Tags: bash, cron

I receive an email with a syntax bash error from the cron deamon on my server like:

```
/etc/cron.daily/maldet: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/etc/cron.daily/maldet: line 29: `fi'
```

I tried some modifications but without success, bash is not my strong language.
The cron daily file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
export LMDCRON=1
. /usr/local/maldetect/conf.maldet
if [ -f "/usr/local/maldetect/conf.maldet.cron" ]; then
    . /usr/local/maldetect/conf.maldet.cron
fi
find=`which find 2> /dev/null`
if [ "$find" ]; then
    # prune any quarantine/session/tmp data older than 7 days
    tmpdirs="/usr/local/maldetect/tmp /usr/local/maldetect/sess /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine /usr/local/maldetect/pub"
    for dir in $tmpdirs; do
     if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
      $find $dir -type f -mtime +7 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f >> /dev/null 2>&1
     fi
    done
fi

if [ "$autoupdate_version" == "1" ] || [ "$autoupdate_signatures" == "1" ]; then
    # sleep for random 1-999s interval to better distribute upstream load
    sleep $(echo $RANDOM | cut -c1-3) >> /dev/null 2>&1
fi

if [ "$autoupdate_version" == "1" ]; then
    # check for new release version
    /usr/local/maldetect/maldet -d >> /dev/null 2>&1
fi

if [ "$autoupdate_signatures" == "1" ]; then
    # check for new definition set
    /usr/local/maldetect/maldet -u >> /dev/null 2>&1
fi
...
```

Any idea why I'm getting this?

Comment: Line 29 would be....?

Comment: @Jens : if [ "$autoupdate_signatures" == "1" ]; then

Answer (score 0):

The script as shown is syntactically correct according to `bash -n script`.
A syntax error could be caused by malformed sourced scripts. What do `bash -n /usr/local/maldetect/conf.maldet` and `bash -n /usr/local/maldetect/conf.maldet.cron` say?

If these are ok, maybe a carriage return (`\r`) snuck in somewhere? To test, run `od -c script` and look for a `\r`.

Comment: bash -n /usr/local/maldetect/conf.maldet doesn't output anything the same with the other. And using od -c script dind't see any \r...very strange

Comment: @calculataur Hmm. Next step: remove the `find=which` part. If find is in the PATH, you don't need it and can use `find $dir ...`. Also, place a `set -x` as the first line after the #! line in the script, remove all redirections to /dev/null and look at the mails sent by cron, which should now be much more verbose. Interestingly, line 29 does not have an `if` statement... Also change all comparisons with `==` to `=`, only the latter is portable.

Comment: Seems to be working now after a reboot and +x. Thanks for the help.